# mongoose nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

what i want, is to only return the _id and data in meta (not my field, but since mongoose has this prime example): [mongoose embedd documents doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html)

so, i'm not looking for any _id in particular, i'm looking for records with meta.votes.length > 0 or meta.fans.length > 0. currently i do:

`Model.find({}, ['_id','meta'], function (err, data) {
  callback(null, data);
});`

i get records with no /data/. i guess an alternative to not finding these sets would be a way to filter them out?

EDIT: i have temporarily resolved my issue with:

`use      : { type: Boolean, default: 1 },`

though this might be a feature (showing and hiding results - old data for instance), i don't consider this a /solution/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `meta.votes` and `meta.fans` are both just Number objects so I don't think you want `meta.fans.length` just access them directly like an int.

This query should retrieve just the _id and meta information for votes > 0

```
Model.find({ "meta.votes" : { $gt : 0 } }, ['_id','meta']).exec(function(err, data) {
   callback(null, data);
});
```

And this query should retrieve just the _id and meta information for fans > 0

```
Model.find({ "meta.fans" : { $gt : 0 } }, ['_id','meta']).exec(function(err, data) {
   callback(null, data);
});
```

And you could pull both queries together like this:

```
Model.find({ $or : [ { "meta.votes" : { $gt : 0 } },
                     { "meta.fans" : { $gt : 0 } } ] }, ['_id','meta']).exec(function(err, data) {
   callback(null, data);
});
```

You should be seeing returns like: `{ _id: 5001b3ce7cf4b534a3000002, meta: { votes: 1, fans: 1 } }`